# get array info in class

Tags: php, php-5.3

I'm trying to use a foreign paying system, but have difficulties in implementing this.

the Class I'm trying to modify looks like this:

```
class MyShop extends Shop {
    var $currency = "EUR";
}
```

and I execute it via

```
$myShop = new MyShop('user', 'pass', TRUE, TRUE);
$result = $myShop->pay();
```

My question now is: how do I get variables from $_POST in this class?
E.g I'm trying to mke the currency dynamic this way..

I already tried the solution posted here: [How to grab data from post to a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556805/how-to-grab-data-from-post-to-a-class)

But I guess I fail miserably at OOPhp :/

Thanks anyway!

Comment: What's the source of `Show`? What's the default constructor's parameters?

Comment: Wow, three downvotes for nothing, thnks!

Comment: You saw the downvotes but not the comments for one of the main reason! Great! :D

Comment: I guess now you understand that you need to read the comments.

Comment: Put in this terms, you need to use the global array `$_POST` in your class, simply using the global variable. But if you are posting, probably there is something missing in the code... Anyway, if this is your question, use `$_POST`. For completeness, I have to tell you that if you are implementing a payment system and you don't know well what you are doing, big issue could happen: each value coming from the user input (as the values in `$_POST`) has to be validated: you cannot simply use the value. For more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223980/the-ultimate-clean-secure-function

Comment: @Aerendir thanks for the short but informative info! BTW: the user gets redirected to the Shops own Mask, so there's not much validation at my point... Thanks!

Comment: @Gotschi It was meant to be `Shop`, sorry! Don't be too much mechanical in checking what people have written.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are multiple solutions. One solution could be to add a setter:

```
class MyShop extends Shop
{
    var $currency = "EUR";

    public function setCurrency($currency)
    {
        $this->currency = $currency;
    }
}

$myShop = new MyShop('user', 'pass', TRUE, TRUE);
$myShop->setCurrency($_POST['currency']);

$result = $myShop->pay();
```

**NOTE**: You can access any `$_POST` variable in any class method. That being said you can set it from constructor if you wish so:

```
class MyShop extends Shop
{
    var $currency = "EUR";

    public function __construct($user, $pass, $param1, $param2)
    {
        parent::__construct($user, $pass, $param1, $param2);

        if (isset($_POST['currency'])) {
             $this->currency = $_POST['currency'];
        }
    }
}

$myShop = new MyShop('user', 'pass', TRUE, TRUE);

$result = $myShop->pay();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out! Works as expected!