# How to grab data from post to a class Object

Tags: php, oop, object, post

I have been trying to write data from a form submit into a PHP class object. I'm using the following basic submit form.

```
<html>
<body>
<h2>Form Submit</h2>
<form action='object_of_array2.php' method='POST'/>
<input type="text" name='first_name' value=''/><br/>
<input type="text" name='last_name' value=''/><br/>
<input type="text" name='email_address' value=''/><br/>
<input type='Submit' name='submit' value='GO'/>
</form>
</html>
</body>
```

I found a previous article,  [How to grab data from post to a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12556805/how-to-grab-data-from-post-to-a-class). Which works with my submit form.

```
    <?PHP
class RegisterUser {
    private $firstName;
    private $lastName;
    private $emailAddress;

    function __construct() {
        $this->firstName = isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : null;
        $this->lastName = isset($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : null;
        $this->emailAddress = isset($_POST['email_address']) ? $_POST['email_address'] : null;
    }

    function start() {
        if (empty($this->firstName) || empty($this->lastName) || empty($this->emailAddress)) {
            echo "Empty Post not allowed";
        }
        else
        {
            // Do some stuiff
            echo " Registration Done";
        }
    }
}

$register = new RegisterUser();
if(!empty($_POST))
{
    $register->start();
}
?>
```

I'm trying to figure out how I could echo $firstname, $lastname & $emailaddress. How can I access these for use elsewhere?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php --- http://phpenthusiast.com/object-oriented-php-tutorials

Comment: *"How can I access these for use elsewhere?"* - You're going to have to elaborate on this.

Comment: This is pretty trivial stuff; just echo on success. I'd of posted an answer, but not knowing exactly what you want to use this for, made me hesitate. Your silence on my comments also added to my hesitation. I hope you enjoy reading those links I gave you, lots of good stuff in there.

Comment: Thanks Fred, I was referring to using the variables to write to MySQL.

Comment: welcome... simply echo `$this->firstName` etc. inside your `// Do some stuiff` and insert into db, if that's what you want to do. There's probably other ways, but that's the quick and dirty way.

Comment: I posted an example for you below. See comments inside it. I hope it does answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty way of doing this, since you want to write the values to a database, as you stated in comments: *"Thanks Fred, I was referring to using the variables to write to MySQL."*.

Simply use the `$this->propertyName` and assign each of them to a variable.

```
else
        {
            // Do some stuiff
            echo " Registration Done" . "<br>";

    $var1 = $this->firstName;
    $var2 = $this->lastName;
    $var3 = $this->emailAddress;


    echo $var1 . " " . $var2 . " " . $var3;

    // write to database here using the assigned variables

    }
```

Note:

Writing to a database would be an entirely different matter and would be out of the scope of the question.

Remember to use a prepared statement at the time of insertion in order to help prevent against an SQL injection.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement

Sidenote about the use of `isset()`.

Using `isset()` is usually best when using radio buttons/checkboxes.

- `empty()` is better when user input is involved.

Reference:

- [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4559925/why-check-both-isset-and-empty)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was using $register -> firstname...so on. Using both or your suggestions work!!